# passing values between processes

Tags: c, parallel-processing, pipe, fork

I am trying to implement a program that will remove numbers from an array that are divisible by odd numbers in the range: 3, 4,...,n one at a time.

This has to be done by creating multiple processes using fork. Each process will remove multiples of a certain odd number in the range 3,4, ...,n and then pass the modified array to the next process which will then remove multiples of the next odd number and then pass it to the next process and pass it to the next process and so on.

For example if I have the array {40, 39, 17 ,15 12, 20, 10}. The first process will remove multiples of 3 then pass {40, 17, 20, 10} to the next process which will remove multiples of 5 and so on.

A new process must be created for each odd number in the range: 3, 4, ..., n. It will work sort of like a "chain".

In the end, the resulting array will be printed to standard output.

NOTE: I know this can be done without using fork and multiple processes but I need to use a fork and then pipes to communicate between processes.

What I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    // array initialized before
    int array[10] = {5, 89, 10, 1 ,2 ,3 ,4, 30, 66, 7};    

    // n is given by command line argument. 
    int n = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    pid_t child;

    // Creating pipes to communicate between processes. 
    int fd[2 * n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        pipe(&fd[2*i]);
    }



    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        child = fork();
        if (child < 0) {
            perror("fork");
            exit(1);
        }
        else if(child > 0){
            // Parent 
            int status;
            wait(&status);
            exit(0);
        }
        else{
            // Child 
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am not sure how to create processes in parallel and then remove elements from the array and then pass it from one process to another using the pipes I created. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This sounds almost exactly like my assignment... :thinking: Mind if I ask where you go to uni, or where this is from?

Comment: You have to view it as parent and child, then another fork and thinking about it as parent and child (with the original parent going 'dark' or unused at that point). It might be cleaner to call exec occasionally or have that grand parent terminate naturally. You don't have to think of it as all processes in the chain staying around for the full runtime

Comment: You are creating pipes, but not using it. See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html which has an example on doing IPC using pipes with single parent-child process. Try to extend it.

Comment: @Snohdo Is the loop and way I’m calling fork correct? So I just need to use pipes now?

Answer (score 0):

I think use the parent child example from the other comment. You have to repeat the fork in the child and architect it as a hierarchy. The first version for something like this might be a bit complex but perhaps it will simplify back close to the parent child example if it's worked on.

Comment: Could you provide some pseudocode to get me started?